# defer - modify named return value vs non-named return value

Tags: function, go, deferred-execution

**Code**

```
func deferModifyReturnValue() int {
    x := 0
    defer func() {
        x += 1 // executed before return,
    }()
    return x
}

func deferModifyNamedReturnValue() (x int) {
    defer func() {
        x += 1 // executed before return,
    }()
    return
}

func TestDeferModifyReturnValue(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Equal(t, 0, deferModifyReturnValue())
    assert.Equal(t, 1, deferModifyNamedReturnValue())
}
```

---

**Question**

The test **passes**.

I can understand why the `deferModifyNamedReturnValue()` return **1**, because defer modify it right before return.

But, how the `deferModifyReturnValue()` return **0**? Does it make a copy to stack before the modification?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements): _"deferred functions are executed after any result parameters are set by that return statement"_

Comment: @JimB Ok, so you mean: A) in the non-named case, a copy to stack is made before the defer function is executed, thus return value is not effected by defer; B) and in the `named return value` case, since the return value is already defined & set, thus the defer take effect. Right ?

Comment: When the result parameter is not named, creating a local variable has no connection to the return value. It doesn't matter if a deferred function changes the value of `x` after the `return` statement: the variable has nothing to do with the value being returned. If `x` itself is the result parameter, its value will be used when the function ends. If a deferred function modifies it after a `return`, the new value will be returned.

Comment: @icza your comment doesn't actually answer my doubt clearly, and the linked question in duplication is not identical to my question neither.

Comment: Whether the result of the return's expression is stored on the stack is irrelevant (can be implementation specific). What matters is that the expression is evaluated when the `return` statement is executed. Deferred functions run _after_ this. In the first example the `x` variable is **not** the result parameter, so again, changing it has no effect on the value being returned.